# Canvasjs divide sum with total row values per day

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, canvasjs

I am working with canvajs ,I need to work with the daily ph value of a specific month.The json output below shows the time stamp converted to only date 12 and 21 of September

> [{"ts":"12","ph":744},{"ts":"21","ph":200}]

Now, my problem is **I wanted to divide ph with the overall number of rows**. The 744 on the above json result is only the sum of the ph on a specific Month.

> ```
>  $sumsep = 0;
>     $sumjul = 0;
>     $data_points = array();
>     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){      
>         $monthNum = date('m',strtotime($row['time_stamp']));
>         $DayNum = date('d', strtotime($row['time_stamp']));     
>         $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
>         $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
>         if($monthNum == "8"){
>             if (array_key_exists($DayNum, $data_points)) {
>                $data_points[$DayNum]->ph += $row['ph'];
>             }else{
> $data_points[$DayNum]->ts = $DayNum;
> $data_points[$DayNum]->ph = $sumsep;
> $point = array("ts"=>date('d',strtotime($row['time_stamp'])),"ph" =>$row['ph']);         
>       }}}}
>     $jsonResult = json_encode(array_values($data_points));     
>     echo $jsonResult;
> ```

I need to divide the 744 and 200 with the number of rows on the specific month.I hope anyone can help me out there.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry tnx for your concern, but do you have any solution for this?

Comment: As commented above.

Comment: @Strawberry, but I guess it wont answer my question

Comment: It's the best shot you've got (even if I say so myself)